# How to set an environment variable in Android?

Tags: android, environment-variables

I'm working on a project where I'm using the Android OS to develop a kiosk application for retail stores. For my purpose, I need to be able to set an environment variable on the Android device that:

1. Is independent of any application;
2. Is persistent across application and system reboots.

***Bonus:*** if I can set the variable from adb, this would be even better.

Surprisingly, this has proved to be more difficult than anticipated.

1. `SharedPreferences` doesn't cut the bill as the variable is dependent on the application that created it.
2. `Os.setenv` sets a variable that is erased as soon as the application is closed or restarted.
3. `adb shell export` seems to have no effect at all.

Anyone has tackled this issue?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `ContentProvider` if you want to expose data to other Android applications using the Android framework/in an Android way. Alternatively, if you have root access and prefer adb, then you may be able to use `setprop` and `getprop`:

```
$ adb shell setprop my.random.prop ok
$ adb shell getprop my.random.prop //outputs "ok"
```

If you have access to Android source you could add a command to `init.rc` that runs this at boot. Or, you could create a file in a location like `data/local`?

**Edit:** Allain has pointed out in the comments that adding `persist` to the property (i.e. `persist.device.id`) allows it to survive reboots.

Comment: `setprop` seems to work. For those who are interested: I've had to add `persist.` (as in `persist.device.id`) for the property to be persistent across reboots.

Comment: I didn't know that - I'll add it to my answer

Answer (score 0):

do this to set using android studio into an app level `build.gradle`

paste your value file in `src/main/res/raw` folder

```
task copySecretKey(type: Copy) {
    def File secretKey = file "$System.env.YOUR_VARIABLE"
    from secretKey.getParent()
    include secretKey.getName()
    into 'src/main/res/raw'
    rename secretKey.getName(), "VALUE_OF_VARIABLE_FROM_RAW_FILE" // in my case it is credential.json
}
preBuild.dependsOn(copySecretKey)
```